What is this object seen above Starship before launching on IFT-6?
While watching Starship a few hours before the launch of IFT-6, I noticed an object (circled in red) above Starship (screenshot below). The launch video is too zoomed out/low resolution for me to identify what it is. So, what is this object?


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

According to Everyday Astronaut, this object is "a border patrol blimp that surveys for marine and air traffic control using radar" which is "tethered on the ground at South Padre Island " and "can see up to 200 miles" ("320 kilometers").
Here's what the object looks like zoomed in:


knew what this was 35 years ago.... core element of COTHEN. At that time is was "Covert Over The Horizon Enforcement Network". The guy at the desk next to mine helped develop it.

"which is "tethered on the ground at South Padre Island"  South Padre Island appears to be outside of the NOTAM area for the launch. This answer shows that the object in the question had nothing do with the SpaceX facility, or the Starship launch, or the launch exclusion zone. It is just an object that happened to be in the field of view of a telephoto lens pointed at the rocket from several miles away. It does not appear to be a space related question, even though at the time the author thought it might be. What if someone asked a similar question which turned out to be a bird?

@StevePemberton "A bird is flying" isn't strange. "A man-made object is flying in a no fly zone hours before a launch" is.

Starship - I will use more words to hopefully make my example more clear. What if someone asked a similar question because they saw an object in a photograph which they could not identify because of the low resolution, which appeared to be above the rocket and perhaps related to the launch since it appeared to be in the no fly zone. Then after the question was asked, they (or someone else) posted an answer showing a different photo with better resolution which showed that the object in question was actually a bird. Would that still be a space related question?

@StevePemberton I think both are space related. The reason one is curious about the object is because its above Starship. If you don't already know the answer, this is reasonable site to ask on. Why should knowing the answer change that?
